# How to get 3 letter abbreviation for month in SQL

Tags: sql-server

How to get month in 3 letters in SQL.

In SQL Table data is inserted:

```
2016-01-07 09:38:58.310
```

I need only month result in 3 letters like below:

```
Jan
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Too many dbms products are far from ANSI SQL compliant when it comes to date/time.)

Comment: SQL 2008 and my select query is like that : SELECT TOP 10 id, Date, Title, Description FROM Table_RecentNews ORDER BY Date DESC.@jarlh

Comment: @zahed - when people ask questions in the comments, it's usually a good idea to [edit] your question, to make it a better question overall, and to specifically include the information asked for (As e.g. marc_s has to re-tag your question, but you might want to to include your full query, which if marked as code (`{}`) will also get nice syntax highlighting)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this (I am assuming you are using Sql Server).

```
Select Convert(char(3), GetDate(), 0)
```

If you need full name of month, try

```
Select Datename(month, GetDate())
```

Comment: my select query is like that : SELECT TOP 10 id, Date, Title, Description FROM Table_RecentNews ORDER BY Date DESC. @Nitin Varpe

Comment: You just need to use above mentioned function and modify your query.

Comment: I need result like.. Date as mmm .. @Nitin Varpe

Comment: SELECT TOP 10 id, Convert(char(3),Date, 0), Title, Description FROM Table_RecentNews ORDER BY Date DESC

Answer (score 30):

Assuming you're using SQL Server **2012** or newer, you can use the `FORMAT` function:

```
SELECT FORMAT([Date], 'MMM', 'en-US')
```

Adapt the locale as needed.

Since you're on SQL Server 2008, I'd use

```
SELECT LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, [Date]), 3)
```

Comment: You were faster :)   `SELECT FORMAT(@d, 'MMM', 'en-US');` [demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/420643)  I would add locale just in case

Comment: I tried this in sql server 2012 but giving error as 'FORMAT' is not a recognized built-in function name. Why??

Comment: @NitinVarpe: you're most likely running SSMS 2012, but against a **pre-2012** database engine. The database **engine** version is the determining factor - not which version of the frontend GUI tool you're using. Check the database engine version using `SELECT @@VERSION`

Comment: Or just `SELECT LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, [Date]), 3)` :)

Comment: @lad2025: darn - you always have these excellent ideas! :-) Updated my response

Comment: SELECT FORMAT([Date], 'MMM', 'en-US') worked for me like charm. Thanks for your answerl.

Answer (score 3):

Or you could just do:

```
LEFT(GETDATE(), 3)
```

For instance you could declare a variable:

```
Declare @MONTH VARCHAR(3)

Set @MONTH = LEFT(GETDATE(), 3)
```